# How to keep anchor active attribute using jquery scroll-to in single page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a homepage where I need my main navigation anchors to stay styled the active color assigned in the css. The issue I am having is I am using a jQuery scrolling function so once the anchor is clicked the corresponding div scrolls up/down/etc. It is all in one HTML file. I would like the anchors in the main nav to stay the active color until another link is clicked. A sample of my code is below:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+id).offset().top -315},'slow');}

<div id="mainnav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('main_content')">HOME</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('page2')">WHY</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('page6')">FEATURES</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('gallery')">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('page4')">DEMO</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('page5')">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

#mainnav{
     height:50px;
     background-color:#FFF;
     float:right;
     font-size:18px;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

  #mainnav a, #mainnav a:link, #mainnav a:visited, {
  color:#444444;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

   #mainnav a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#BAB9B9;}

    #mainnav a:active{
    color:#f69512;
    text-decoration: none;}


#page2{
    clear:both;
    min-width:990px;
    background-color:#c8c8c8;
    min-height:600px;
    top:380px;
    bottom:65px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link, give it a class with the same apparence properties like the active state.

And when you click another link, leave this class from all the links and add it to the clicked link.

You can leave the onclick attributes and just declare the events  like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a', '#mainnav').on('click', function(){
    $('a', '#mainnav').removeClass('imactive');
    $(this).addClass('imactive');
    return false;
  })
})
```

Comment: I added the script and a .imactive{color:#f69512;text-decoration:none;
} in the CSS. It is not calling the color.

Comment: #mainnav a.imageactive{color:#f69512;text-decoration:none;}